# Simple Authorization Service Provider using dependency injection unity Config

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

I am working on application in which i want to inject IAuthrepository in SimplerAuthorizationServiceProvider using Dependency Injection. But when i run the application it return me null exception. Here is my code.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888

    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    UnityConfig.Register(config);
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    ConfigureOAuth(app);
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}

public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
        Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider((IAuthRepository)GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IAuthRepository)))
    };
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

}
```

Here is SimpleAuthorizationServiceProvider Class

```
    public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        private IAuthRepository _repo;
        public SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(IAuthRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }
        public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            if (context.ClientId == null)
            {
                context.Validated();
            }
        }
        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
                IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                    return;
                }
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));
                context.Validated(identity);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When i run the application **_repo** is always null due to which it gives me null exception. Here is registering Repositories.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
            config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
        }
```

Comment: you try to resolve from global config but the config used to register was the one you manually created in the `Configuration` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to resolve from static `GlobalConfiguration` but the `HttpConfiguration` used to register dependencies was the instance you manually created in the `Configuration` method

Refactor to use the local configuration instance

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {    
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    UnityConfig.Register(config);
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    ConfigureOAuth(app, config.DependencyResolver);
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}

public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app, IDependencyResolver resolver) {
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions() {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
        Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider((IAuthRepository)resolver.GetService(typeof(IAuthRepository)))
    };
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());    
}
```